# It appears as I can't renew an object

Tags: java, object, stack

I am creating and then removing items from stack. In here I am passing original deck to a method where I try to decide if deck is now empty. If is empty, I want to reset the deck by creating new deck and referencing it back to original deck.

What's wrong with my logic? I know there's something wrong because when I reach the end of the deck and finally if-statement kicks in it won't let me to escape later on and is stuck on telling me that deck is empty.

```
private static Deck checkDeck(Deck deck)
{
    if(deck.isEmpty())
    {
        System.out.print("Deck is empty! You must recreate and reshuffle deck of cards!\n\n");
        System.out.println("Creating deck...");
        deck = new Deck(DECKSIZE);
        deck.createDeck();
        System.out.println("Shuffling deck...");
        deck.shuffleDeck();
        System.out.print("\n");
    }

    return deck;
}
```

The Main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
    Deck deck = null;
    Hand playersHand = null;
    Hand dealersHand = null;

    System.out.println("Creating deck...");
    deck = new Deck(DECKSIZE);
    deck.createDeck();

    // Remove elements of deck...

    deck = checkDeck(deck);

    temp = new Card(deck.pop());
    System.out.println("Drawing players card... " + temp.toString());
    playersHand.insert(temp);
}
```

Sample output run:

```
deal, bet, hit, stay, split, leave: deal

Drawing players card... 9 ♣
Drawing dealers card... 6 ♠
Drawing players card... 11 ♠
Drawing dealers card... 13 ♥

Dealers Hand: K_♥ 6_♠ = 16
Players Hand: J_♠ 9_♣ = 19

deal, bet, hit, stay, split, leave: deal

Deck is empty! You must recreate and reshuffle deck of cards!

Creating deck...
Shuffling deck...

Drawing players card... 13 ♥
Drawing dealers card... 6 ♣
Drawing players card... 7 ♠
Drawing dealers card... 11 ♣

Dealers Hand: J_♣ 6_♣ = 16
Players Hand: 7_♠ K_♥ = 17

deal, bet, hit, stay, split, leave: deal

Deck is empty! You must recreate and reshuffle deck of cards!

Creating deck...
Shuffling deck...

Drawing players card... 4 ♦
Drawing dealers card... 9 ♥
Drawing players card... 3 ♥
Drawing dealers card... 9 ♦

Dealers Hand: 9_♦ 9_♥ = 18
Players Hand: 3_♥ 4_♦ = 7

deal, bet, hit, stay, split, leave:
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the Constructor of `Deck` and the `createDeck()` method?

Comment: Have you looked at the debugging and checked, if the two objects are really different? The code itself looks fine to me.

Comment: Also: What do you mean `it won't let me to escape later on and is stuck on telling me that deck is empty.`? escape from where/when?

Comment: can you post the push() method?

Comment: deal, bet, hit, stay, split, leave: they use only pop() to get the deck card?

Comment: @Bo PENG, in my program only deal and hit work so far but they use basically same principle. And yes. They draw a card so they pop out a card out of the deck (since we don't want to reuse cards). When deck is empty I need to generate a new deck of cards.

Comment: Since we can't seem to be making any further progress with the information we have, I suggest that you use a debugger (e.g. in Eclipse) to figure out what happens to the Deck at each interesting step. It might be helpful for this to give Deck a toString method that shows a summary of the contents (e.g. number of cards, or the list of all cards).

Comment: can you add the code where you are looping and asking the "player" to choose the action?

Answer (score 0):

The `checkDeck()` function uses a function that the main function doesn't, and that you did not show (`Deck.shuffleDeck()`). Given the code you did show, my best guess is that the error is in there.

Comment: `public void shuffleDeck()
 {
  Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(stackArray));
 }`

Answer (score 0):

For what I've seen your code seems to be OK.
The problem should be wherever you are doing the loop, and asking the action to the "player".
It seems that you are either creating a new empty deck each time or getting the rest of the cards out during this loop.